# Redux UI wont update when changing state of nested array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

I'm fairly new to Redux.

My Web application is an eCommerce website where users have multiple carts (each with an id and name) and can place different items in each cart (inside an items array).

When a user deletes an item from the cart, my `console.log()` statements show that the carts array is being updated in the store, however the User interface doesn't reflect that unless i insert a new cart object inside of the carts array.

1. Why can't i update a nested array the same way i update a normal array in the store?
2. How do i fix this?

---

**My initial Store**

```
const intialStore = {
    carts: [],
    first_name : "ford",
    last_name : "doly"

}
```

---

**My Reducer Function**

```
export default function reducer (store = intialStore, action) {
    let {type, payload} = action;
    switch(type) {

     case DELETE_ITEM_IN_A_CART : {
    
                let carts = [...store.carts]
    
    
  let newCarts =   carts.map((cartItem, index) => {
    
                    if (index == payload.cartIndex){
    
                        let array = [...cartItem.items]
                        array.splice(payload.itemIndex, 1) 
    
                        cartItem.items = [...array  ]
                    }
    
                    
                    
    
                    return cartItem ;
                })
    
            
                console.log(carts)
    
                //carts[payload.cartIndex].items.splice(payload.itemIndex, 1)
    
               
               
                return {...store, carts : newCarts}
            }

       default:
          return {...store}
}
```

---

**My Action Creator**

```
export const deleteitemInCart = (cartIndex, itemIndex) => {
    return {
        type: DELETE_ITEM_IN_A_CART,
        payload: {
            cartIndex,
            itemIndex
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the spread operator, you're only making a shallow copy. In your reducer, try using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(carts))` in order to make a deep copy before performing the splice operation. This would ensure you are not mutating any existing state, but operating on a copy and returning a new copy at the end of the reducer.

Comment: You were 100% correct. Can't thank you enough as i have been stuck on this for 3/4 days now. I will award you the +50 rep when the timer allows me

Answer (score 1):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array, it does not mutate the original (which is good, we don't want to mutate it). But this means in order for your mapping actions to be persisted, you need to assign the result to a variable.

```js
let newCarts = carts.map(...)

...

return {...store, carts: newCarts}
```

Right now, you're just returning the same carts array as the new state.

Comment: I did that but the updated items array is still not being reflected  on the UI